# Objective C - iPhone/IPad app -Weird Issue with storyboard not reflecting the changes on the app

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode4.6

I am working on a app for universal (both iPhone and iPad) environments. To avoid building UI again. I copied over the storyboard from my app that I had worked for iPhone.(I have to enhance it further) and renamed it MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard and MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard. The UI on both iphone and ipad simulator works fine with the old UI.

Even the new  code changes works fine however the changes on the UI such as label text, button text and add/remove new UI components on the storyboard are not reflecting on the app. The app still shows the old UI after building. I tried clean build etc. Looked at the storyboard in text editor the new added /updated components are indeed there but they just don't show up on the app.

Any clue what's might be going wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

Besides copying the storyboard, did you also set the correct storyboard on the 'Summary' page of your project's target for iPad Deployment?

[image]

Comment: Oh Ya!! Devices = Universal and I could see both iPad/iPhone Deployment Info.

Comment: I've just created an iPhone-only project; duplicated the Storyboard; set the project to universal; set the correct Storyboard in 'deployment info' for iPad; changed some UI stuff; and it worked as expected...

Comment: The deployment info shows iPhone/iPad Deployment Info isnt it? and the Main Storyboard - Mainstoryboard_iPhone and Mainstoryboard_iPad respectively.

Comment: So, alle items appear to have correct values? Any progress sofar?